# What sort of matrix norms bound traces of products?

Tags: trace, matrix-norms

Suppose I have some linear operators $X_1, \dots, X_n$ on $\mathbb{C}^r$ (i.e. $r \times r$ matrices) and some other operators $Y_1^\epsilon, \dots, Y_n^\epsilon$ which are deformations of the $X_i$, by which I mean I can bound the differences
$$
\| X_i - Y_i^\epsilon \|
$$
by a function of $\epsilon$ which goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is some norm.

I want to show that
$$
\operatorname{tr} (Y_1^\epsilon \cdots Y_n^\epsilon) \to \operatorname{tr}(X_1 \cdots X_n)
$$
as $\epsilon \to 0$. What type of norm $\| \cdot \|$ should I consider to show this limiting relationship on the traces?

I might be able to assume that the $Y_i^\epsilon$ and $X_i$ have the same eigenvalues for each $i$.

Comment: By operators on $\mathbb{C}^r$, do you mean $r\times r$ matrices ?

Comment: By "operator" I mean "linear operator" so yes.

Comment: For matrices, the inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle=\mbox{tr}(X^{T}Y)$ is associated with the Froebnious norm in that $\langle X,X \rangle=\| X \|_{F}^{2}$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I can see how the Frobenius norm might be helpful but it's not obvious (to me) how to apply it here. Is it just playing with inner products, or is there something more involved?

Comment: The point is that you'd at least have a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that you could apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you are in a finite dimensional space, all the norms are equivalent. So yes, $\|X\|_{2} := (\mathrm{tr}(X^*X))^{1/2}$, proposed by Borchers, is a good norm. Other good norms are the trace norm $\|X\|_{1} := \mathrm{tr}(|X|)$ where $|X| = (X^*X)^{1/2}$, the operator norm $\|X\| = \|X\|_{\infty} = \sup{\{\text{eigenvalues}\}}$. In all these norms, you have Hölder's inequality
$$
\mathrm{tr}(XY) ≤ \|X\|_2\|Y\|_2
\\
\mathrm{tr}(XY) ≤ \|X\|_1\|Y\|.
$$
Then you can write $\mathrm{tr}(Y_1Y_2Y_3) = \mathrm{tr}((Y_1-X_1)Y_2Y_3)+\mathrm{tr}(X_1Y_2Y_3) = \dots = \mathrm{tr}((Y_1-X_1)Y_2Y_3)+\mathrm{tr}(X_1(Y_2-X_2)X_3)+\mathrm{tr}(X_1X_2(Y_3-X_3))+\mathrm{tr}(X_1X_2X_3)$ and you can use Hölder's inequality to get the convergence you need.

Comment: Thanks! This was quite helpful.